# reftex (select a label type)

Tags: reftex-mode

When I use Reftex to insert a reference (i.e., `M-x reftex-reference` or `C-c )`), I am prompted to select a label type in a new window:

> SELECT A LABEL TYPE:
>   --------------------
>   [ ]   any
>   [e]   eqnarray equation Beqnarray subequations xxalignat xalignat alignat flalign multline gather align
>   [f]   figure* figure wrapfigure \subfigure subfigure* subfigure SCfigure sidewaysfigure tabwindow figwindow floatingfigure
>   [i]   enumerate
>   [l]   minted lstlisting
>   [n]   \footnote
>   [N]   \endnote
>   [s]   section
>   [t]   table* table \ctable wraptable supertabular SCtable sidewaystable       longtable

How do I choose "any" - what does `[ ]` mean?

Is it possible to remove this step and always choose the "any" ?

Comment: does  [this link to the official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.html#SEC12) help?

Answer (score 1):

In this case `[ ] any` means press the space key.